# How to handle this on JMeter - System.FormatException: Invalid length for a Base-64 char array or string

Tags: jmeter

I already configured the token but I am trying to have a csv file for the login credentials. the login credentials generate code

Answer (score 0):

Try BeanShell processor script to create a base 64 enoded char array and pass that as login credentials.

```
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;
log.info(“Base64 Encoding ClientID & ClientPassword”);
//Create the complete string which needs to be encoded
String forEncoding = vars.get(“ClientID”) + “:” + vars.get(“ClientPassword”);
log.info(“forEncoding: “ + forEncoding);
//Encode the string
byte[] encoded_ClientCredentials = Base64.encodeBase64(forEncoding.getBytes());
//Save the encoded byte array into a String Variable
vars.put(“encoded_ClientCredentials”, new String(encoded_ClientCredentials));
log.info(“encoded_ClientCredentials: “ + vars.get(“encoded_ClientCredentials”));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to provide [Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64)-encoded credentials you could use [__base64Encode() function](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/Functions/#base64Encodesupfont-color-gray-size-1-since-1-2-0-font-sup) which is available via [Custom JMeter Functions](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/Functions/#Custom-JMeter-Functions) bundle which can be installed using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/)

See [How to Use the Custom JMeter Functions Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-use-the-custom-jmeter-functions-plugin) article for more details.

---

From your question it's not really clear how the credentials should be passed, if it's about [Basic Access Control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication) it might be much easier to use [HTTP Authorization Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Authorization_Manager)